# Mounting droboshare from linux

Tags: mount, fstab

I am attempting to mount a drobo (via droboshare attached to the network) from linux and running into roadblocks and have run out of ideas.

When I issue the smbclient -L IPADDRESS I get the following:

```
Domain=[COMPANYDOMAIN] OS=[Unix] Server=[Sambe 3.0.14a]

Sharename     Type     Comment
----------    ------   ----------
FILESHARE     Disk     Comment entered
IPC$          IPC      IPC Service (DroboShare)
ADMIN$        IPC      IPC Service (DroboShare)
Domain=[COMPANYDOMAIN] OS=[Unix] Server=[Sambe 3.0.14a]

Server             Comment
-------------      --------------
SERVERNAME         DroboShare

Workgroup          Master
-------------      --------------
LOCALWORKGROUP
```

From this, if I enter the following command:
sudo ntfs-3g //IPADDRESS/FILESHARE /mnt/mountpoint (this directory IS created)
I receive this error:
ntfs-3g: Failed to access volume (lists IP and share): No such file or directory

This could be due to attempting to connect with the incorrect file system, though I would think the error would be different. So, does anyone see the issue? Can anyone tell me how I can confirm the filesystem in use on the Drobo? Do I need to add some additional packages to enable this connection?

Ultimately we would like the mount configured in FSTAB, but first we need to make sure it works.

Thanks in advance for any guidance you can offer.

Greg

Answer (score 0):

Do not believe that you really want to utilise ntfs-3g as your FS mount type, as this is on a Windows network, correct? If so, try utilising CIFS instead. My suggestion here is that since this is Droboshare, you may want to review [this article](http://www.dh1tw.de/mounting-drobo-with-linux-ubuntu), which also describes using CIFS as the FS type, not ntfs-3g.

Hope that helps. It is a simple FS type error, and if you follow that article, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest try to access droboshare using nautilus.

Open Nautilus file manager and press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>   +  <kbd>L</kbd>.
Write `smb://<ipaddress>/<sharename>` in search bar and press enter.

You should be able to open droboshare if you have correct share address.